# How to define policies for Python application in Bluemix Autoscaling service?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, autoscaling

I noticed that the policy types depend on the target runtime. For example, for Java it is possible to define policies based on memory, throughput, response time... etc. The only possibility for Python is memory based policy. Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix Auto scaling service for Liberty for Java™ applications, supports scaling rules for JVM Heap, Memory, and Throughput. Actually, Auto Scaling services on Bluemix works with IBM JVM.

For other types of runtimes, including Python runtime, there is only [scaling rules](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Auto-Scaling/index.html) for Memory.